# Github pages site size limits?

Tags: github-pages

What are the limitations on the amount of data on github pages?

Main github repo a limited in 1 GB (https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/), and what about github pages?

**UPD**

On http://www.quora.com/What-are-bandwidth-and-traffic-limits-for-GitHub-pages I found two much different answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

GitHub now has new policies of a 1GB filesize repository, warnings for pushes of files over 50 MB and complete rejection for fileuploads of 100MB. GitHub warns you when you push a file larger than 50 MB.

https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/

Comment: So having Github pages with a javascript galley is no problem :), you'll upload files less than 50gb :)

Answer (score 17):

Related is bandwidth usage (amount of data transferred). There is a limit but it isn't documented. Taken from the [GitHub Terms of Service](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/):

> If your bandwidth usage significantly exceeds the average bandwidth
>   usage (as determined solely by GitHub) of other GitHub customers, we
>   reserve the right to immediately disable your account or throttle your
>   file hosting until you can reduce your bandwidth consumption.

Answer (score 9):

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#guidelines-for-using-github-pages

> #### [Usage limits](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#usage-limits)
>
> GitHub Pages sites are subject to the following usage limits:
>
> - GitHub Pages source repositories have a recommended limit of 1GB. For more information, see "[What is my disk quota?](https://docs.github.com/en/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#file-and-repository-size-limitations)"
> - Published GitHub Pages sites may be no larger than 1 GB.
> - GitHub Pages sites have a *soft* bandwidth limit of 100GB per month.
> - GitHub Pages sites have a *soft* limit of 10 builds per hour.

Comment: Does "Published GitHub Pages sites may be no larger than 1 GB" means 1GB overall my pages or 1GB for each github page?