# How can I use git lfs with Travis CI gh-pages deploy?

Tags: git, travis-ci, github-pages, git-lfs

So currently I am trying to automatically deploy large files above 100 mb to github pages with travis, is that possible?

Is it possible to configure travis to do this in the deploy step rat
After testing a lot of different methods, I used a script to install git lfs and it successful pushed my changes to the repo.

Would having large files in the repo cause a travis pages deploy to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since git-lfs is used for external storage for large binaries, and due to the limits on GitHub pages (see [Github pages site size limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706454/github-pages-site-size-limits)), it seems unlikely that git-lfs files are "usable".