# Display interactive plotly chart (.html file) on GitHub Pages

Tags: python, html, markdown, plotly, github-pages

I've created the following plotly plot like this:

```
import plotly
labels = ['Oxygen', 'Hydrogen', 'Carbon_Dioxide', 'Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]

trace = plotly.graph_objs.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)
plotly.offline.plot([trace], filename='basic-pie-chart')
```

Then I created the html as such:

```
print(plotly.offline.plot([trace], include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div'))
```

Running the code above generates an .html file that I can view in my browser.

Is there a way to display the .html file in the middle of a markdown file on my GitHub Pages, so I can use the interactive features of plotly?

[Here is a similar question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679392/how-to-link-html-file-from-jekyl-markdown-post)

Answer (score 8):

If you use [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) in your GitHub pages site.

Prepare your data:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)])
fig.show()
```

Generate HTML file:

```
import plotly.io as pio

pio.write_html(fig, file='figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

Upload the `figure.html` file and commit it to `_includes` folder in the root of your site repository.

Now if you are using [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to create your posts, you can use [include](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) tag and call `figure.html` in your post with something like this:

```
{% include figure.html %}
```

Commit this line to your post `.md` file in the `_posts` folder. Check results.

Comment: I did the what you suggested, but when I pushed my commits I got an email from GitHub saying "The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error: Page build failed" What could I have done wrong? Here's a link to the .md file in question: https://github.com/ethanfuerst/ethanfuerst.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2020-3-3-imdb1.md

Comment: @Ethan I need more details... Error message should contain more information https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites Probably your post is too large, 7plots*3.15MB=22MB. The average web page is 3MB. You can overcome GitHub bandwidth usage. There is a limit but it isn't documented. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706454/github-pages-site-size-limits

Comment: I tried to remove everything but one plot, and I still go the same error. Do you know how I can check the size of an article?Also, there was no specific error in the email. Here's the whole contents: "The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#troubleshooting-build-errors.

For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:

  https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds"

Comment: Generic build failures will not produce an email with specific file and error information. If you receive an email that simply says "Page build failed" with no further details, or your GitHub Pages site is not showing up after the first push, check for these common errors. https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds

Comment: I've looked through all those, but none of the supposed fixes work with my repository. I submitted an issue through github, hopefully they can show me the answer and I will post here

Answer (score 0):

I just published a browser extension [xhub](https://github.com/nschloe/xhub), that adds plotly support to all GitHub pages (including READMEs etc.).

[image]

It works via JSON and is specified in markdown as

````markdown
```plotly
{
  "data": [ ... ],
  "layout": { ... }
}
```
````

If you don't have the extension installed, you'll just see the markdown code block of course.

Comment: broken link. Does the package/tool still exist?