# How to link .html file from Jekyl markdown post?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I've got a GitHub pages website and I am trying to link to an .html file that is in a folder in the repository from one of my posts. The html files are in a folder called html, and I've added the following to my _config.yml file:

```
    include:
      - html
```

I've tried:

```
[Link](/html/html_file.html)
```

but that sends me to a 404 page when I click the link. I tried:

```
[Link]({% link /html/html_file.html %})
```

but I get an email from GitHub that says the page build failed. The following gives me the same error.

```
{{ site.baseurl }}({% link /html/html_file.html %})
```

Any ideas how I can link to this .html file?

I've exhausted the following resource
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts

Comment: If your GitHub repo is not private, please share the URL to the repo.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/ethanfuerst/ethanfuerst.github.io