# Plotly graphs not showing through github on jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a .ipynb file that has some plotly figures that are called with `fig.show()` at the end of the cell. Here is an example pulled from their documentation:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))

fig.show()
```

When I run this code in a jupyter notebook, the interactive plot will show but when I save and commit my changes, the interactive plot does not show through the .ipynb viewer on github or https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/

[Here is an example of the notebook file on my github](https://github.com/ethanfuerst/mpg_data/blob/master/mpg_vis.ipynb)

How can I get the interactive plot to show in github?

Comment: It doesn't work interactively on the 'plotly' [Github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py) page. Naturally, that's because we're not in an environment where 'plotly' can run.

Comment: @r-beginners is there a way that I can display the interactive graphs on my github? I have a github pages but ran in to a similar issue displaying plotly graphs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60513164/display-interactive-plotly-chart-html-file-on-github-pages

Comment: I have reviewed the link that will be your comment.
Maybe 'GIthub Pages' can do it. I haven't used it so I can't be sure.