# Github page limits for each or overall?

Tags: github, limit, github-pages

Citing github page limits:

> "Published GitHub Pages sites may be no larger than 1 GB"

Does this means 1GB overall my pages or 1GB for each github page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github pages site size limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706454/github-pages-site-size-limits)

Comment: It's about the same topic, but not exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit means the site as a whole; that is, all of the pages taken together.

Since a GitHub Pages site is designed to be used as a website for your open source project or as a personal site, and as a practical matter 1 GB for a single web page is too large to render in a modern web browser efficiently, it wouldn't be logical for GitHub to state that a single web page may be at most 1 GB.

Comment: Thanks, but your reasoning is: because "1GB for a single web page is too large" -> No.
But, what about, for example, embedded games?

Comment: I very much doubt any web browser is going to load a full gigabyte of any webpage into memory because web pages have to be parsed into many components, increasing the amount of memory used, so a 1 GB webpage will make the browser take much more memory.  Browser games are going to use many smaller chunks of assets that are loaded independently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!